# Why can't advisory locks be unlocked while in a transaction with pg-promise?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg-promise

I ran across the following code and was trying to debug it, but I don't understand why the lock couldn't be unlocked in this scenario:

```js
const db = pgp(opts)

await db.one('SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(1) AS lock') // returns true, and I can see the lock in the DB

// no await 
db.tx(async t => {
      const fingerprintIds = fingerprints.map(item => item.id)
      sql = `UPDATE fingerprint SET blah=1 WHERE id IN ($(fingerprintIds:list)) RETURNING id`
      const updatedFingerprintIds = await db.query(sql, { fingerprintIds }) // yes, it is not using the transaction object 

      // some other database calls
    })

result = await db.one('SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(1) AS lock')
// result.lock === false, database logs the error: 'WARNING:  you don't own a lock of type ExclusiveLock'
// lock still stays in the database (until the session ends)
```

Of course, when I add the `await` in front of the `db.tx` call, and use `t` in the transaction callback, then it works as expected.

Does this happen because the pg-promise library is in a transactional state when the `unlock` is called? Because when I call this succession of queries, the lock will unlock as expected:

```
SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(1) AS lock;
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM table;
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(1) AS lock;
```

Comment: I don't know pg-promise, but (session-level) advisory locks are independent of transactions.

Comment: [Documentation explains](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/chaining-queries) how and when to use tasks and transactions. Why won't you just follow that pattern? The code above is bad, because you create a transaction context, and then do not actually use it.

Comment: Yes, I realize that :) this is not my code, but I was trying to understand the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lock operations are exclusive to the current connection session, and so they must be executed within the same transaction block:

```js
await db.tx(async t => {

    await t.func('pg_try_advisory_lock', [1]);

    // execute all queries here, against 't' context;
    // ...

    await t.func('pg_advisory_unlock', [1]);

});
```

- We use method [func](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func) here just to shorten the syntax.

That however won't execute the unlock, if the transaction fails, so if that's a concern, then you will need to manually catch errors inside the transaction:

```js
await db.tx(async t => {

    await t.func('pg_try_advisory_lock', [1]);

    let result, err;

    try {
        // execute all queries here, against 't' context;
        // and set the 'result'...

    } catch(e) {
        err = e;
    }

    await t.func('pg_advisory_unlock', [1]);

    if(e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return result;
});
```

**UPDATE**

> I’m using an advisory lock because there are a lot of other things (non-idempotent, non-database) that happen outside of this one database transaction, and since there are multiple instances of the app running, the lock is to prevent other instances from doing the same work at the same time

I'm not sure how this type of lock can help across multiple databases or even multiple apps, since those locks can only work within the same session.

But if you really need to execute those locks outside of the transaction, and yet against the same connection, then you would need to manage the connection manually:

```js
// Somewhere in the beginning of your chain logic,
// you allocate a manually-managed connection:
const dbm = await db.connect();

// Then your lock happens:
await dbm.func('pg_try_advisory_lock', [1]);


// Then you transaction happens...
await dbm.tx(async t => {
    // transaction queries
});

// Then your unlock query:
await dbm.func('pg_advisory_unlock', [1]);

// Then you release the connection:
dbm.done();
```

You just have to be careful with this, not to leak connections ;)

- See method [connect](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#connect).

Comment: The example is a bit contrived, I couldn’t just insert the lock inside the transaction block, because the calls to lock and unlock are much further up in the call stack. I was just trying to understand why the lock couldn’t be unlocked while starting to execute a transaction, but I could do it in raw sql

Comment: @BrDaHa Is there any benefit in executing a lock before the `BEGIN`?

Comment: I’m using an advisory lock because there are a lot of other things (non-idempotent, non-database) that happen outside of this one database transaction, and since there are multiple instances of the app running, the lock is to prevent other instances from doing the same work at the same time

Comment: @BrDaHa I don't get it. The lock that you are using, is session-specific, which means it works only against the current connection. It is not something that can be used across multiple database instances or multiple apps.

Comment: Single database, multiple apps. Try advisory lock does return false for other apps (different sessions) if they don’t get the lock first.

Comment: @BrDaHa See the update. I can only provide a general advise on that. You will have to work out out details on your own ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208667/discussion-between-vitaly-t-and-brdaha).

Comment: @BrDaHa Did this not help?

Comment: I wasn’t trying to make the broken code work by using connection management juggling, I was just trying to understand why that happened. Were you able to reproduce the behavior?